# DBI: sql_type_cast - question

Tags: sql, perl, casting, dbi

Do I something wrong or is `sql_type_cast` not supported by my constellation?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);

my $dsn = "DBI:Proxy:hostname=horst;port=2000;dsn=DBI:ODBC:db1.mdb";
my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, undef, undef, { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0 } ) 
or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sv = '4.8g';
my $sql_type = SQL_DOUBLE;
my $flags = DBIstcf_DISCARD_STRING;

my $sts = DBI->sql_type_cast( $sv, $sql_type, $flags );
```

dies with

```
# Usage: DBI::sql_type_cast(sv, sql_type, flags=0) at ./perl.pl line 14.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the manual.  `sql_type_cast` must be called as a function, not a method.  Try:

```
my $sts = DBI::sql_type_cast( $sv, $sql_type, $flags );
```

(Note that `->` has been changed to `::`.)

Comment: Thanks - I've fixed that in the subversion trunk.